# access NSColorPanel's bottom/custom colors

Tags: macos, cocoa, nscolorpanel

I would like to read the list of colors that are shown on the bottom of the `NSColorPanel` (see image below). Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For undocumented access (this may not work within a sandbox and **will get your app rejected by Apple if you plan to distribute through the App Store**):

```
NSArray *libraries = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSLibraryDirectory inDomains:NSAllDomainsMask];
NSURL *url = [[libraries objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Colors/NSColorPanelSwatches.plist"];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:fileData];

NSArray *colors = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"NSSwatchColorArray"];
```

The `colors` array will then contain `NSColor` objects of the colour panel.

This works as far back as OS X 10.6. It may work on earlier versions also but you'll need to obtain the filename differently (since `URLsForDirectory:inDomains:` was introduced in 10.6). Inside the `NSColorPanelSwatches.plist` file is an internal version number which is set to `6` for 10.6 right through to 10.10. It could change in the future, but you could be more-or-less safe by doing:

```
if ([unarchiver decodeIntForKey:@"NSSwatchFileVersion"] == 6)
{
    NSArray *colors = [unarchiver objectForKey:@"NSSwatchColorArray"];
    // do something with colors
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"System unsupported");
}
```

If you're interested in where the positions of the colours are, you can decode an `NSIndexSet` from the unarchiver using the `NSSwatchColorIndexes` key, and use that index set in conjunction with the number of rows and columns that you can determine by decoding integers with the keys `NSSwatchLayoutNumRows` and `NSSwatchLayoutNumColumns`. The *n*th index in the index set refers to the location of the *n*th colour in the array and the indexes increase downwards. For example, the first “colour box” in the panel is index 0, and the box below it is index 1. The box to the right of “index 0” is actually index 10 (or whatever number you decoded from `NSSwatchLayoutNumRows`).

So if you have a colour in the first box, and another colour in the box to the right, you'll have two `NSColor` objects in the `colors` array, and the `NSIndexSet` will contain two indexes, 0 and 10.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are no public APIs for accessing system-wide user-provided colors from the swatches. This is a very old issue. `NSColorPanel` is long overdue for an overhaul from Apple...